# Como instalar o lua via terminal no ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, lua, terminal

Como instalar o lua via terminal no ubuntu?

Quando eu tento `apt-get install lua` é retornado

```
O pacote lua é um pacote virtual fornecido por:
  lua5.1 5.1.5-5ubuntu0.1
  lua50 5.0.3-7
  lua5.2 5.2.3-1
```

Comment: Falta a versão. `apt-get install lua5.2`, por exemplo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa especificar a versão que deseja instalar. Algo como

> ```
> $> sudo apt-get install lua5.2
> ```

Veja: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lua5.2